# mysql (copy) insert into from select and add one alias column

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

test_table:

```
id   data_text
1    *some text*
```

undo_test_table:

```
id   data_text    modification_date
```

.

```
CREATE TRIGGER undo_trigger BEFORE UPDATE 
ON test_table
FOR EACH ROW 

INSERT INTO undo_test_table SELECT *,NOW() AS modification_date
FROM test_table 
WHERE id = NEW.id
```

What I try with that, is if one column on first table is modified then the trigger (undo_trigger) is fired and copy entire row to another table (undo_test_table )

But in the second table (undo_test_table ) I have one more column (modification_date)

**The problem:**

**The above example working good** but I don't know how to make that working if I change the (modification_date) column at first place instead as last place in (undo_test_table)
like this:

undo_test_table:

```
modification_date   id   data_text
```

I have tried :

```
SELECT NOW() AS modification_date,* FROM test_table ...
```

instead

```
SELECT *,NOW() AS modification_date FROM test_table ...
```

But got sintax error.

I think i need some like an UNION but I don't know how I can use **NOW() AS modification_date** in one UNION

Comment: The name of the table is `undo_test_table`, but your code says `test_table_undo`.

Comment: Thanks ... only misspelled I have rectified now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to qualify the `*` with the table's name:

```
SELECT NOW() AS modification_date, t.* 
-- Here ---------------------------^
FROM   test_table
-- etc...
```

Comment: It needs to be in the other order: `t.*, NOW()` so that it matches the order of the columns in `undo_test_table`.

Comment: This was the problem: what if the order of columns are changed?. So the @Mureinik answer is right

Comment: @MTK It's generally best to list columns explicitly, so you're not dependent on the two tables having columns in the same order.

Comment: @Barmar I take note. Thanks